# How to fix 'layout' method undefined in Laravel 8 with livewire

Tags: visual-studio-code, laravel-8, intelephense

I am using `vscode` when i make a component .. it gives me an error `undefined method` at `layout` even if i replace it with `extends` the `intelephense` plugin gives me the same error

i installed `ide_helper` but it didn't work .. however the code works fine as expected

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;


use Livewire\Component;


class AdminGradeComponent extends Component
{

  public function render()
  {
    return view('livewire.home-component')->layout('layouts.app'); //error here at layout
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Source https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/2079.

The `view()` return type is an interface that does not declare the layout method.
Create a file in the root directory of you application, like this:

```
<?php
  namespace Illuminate\Contracts\View;
  use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable;    
  interface View extends Renderable
  {
    /** @return static */
    public function extends();
    public function layoutData();
    public function layout();
    //any other method that throws false error here :)
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

here you need to close the round bracket...it´s missing

```
view('livewire.home-component'->
```

UPDATED:
then nevermind it...I'm also facing this in JB
[image]

Comment: sorry .. it's a typo when i write the question .. but it closed in my code

Comment: i'm facing the same in JB...nevermind it!

Answer (score -1):

If you have a PHP Intelephense extension enable in your vscode then try to disable it.